# Automatically adding a class to a list through a class decorator?

Tags: javascript, decorator

Is it possible to get a handle to the "class object" (constructor) in a decorator?

Background: I want to parse a json'ish format with string values that are tagged with types, e.g. `"@date:2019-01-25"` or `"@latlong:51.507351,-0127758"`.

This is a modernization effort of an older js library where this was achieved by overriding both subclassing and instance creation.

Decorators looked promising, at least I can define the tag as a class attribute:

```
function dkdatatype({tag}) {
    return function decorator(cls) {
        if (cls.kind !== 'class') throw `not class ${cls.kind}`;

        cls.elements.push({
            kind: 'field',
            key: 'tag',
            placement: 'static', 
            descriptor: {
                configurable: false,
                enumerable: true,
                writable: false
            },
            initializer: () => tag
        });

        return {
            kind: 'class',
            elements: cls.elements
        };
    };
}

@dkdatatype({tag: '@date:'})
export class DkDate extends datatype {
    constructor(...args) {
        super();
        const clstag = this.constructor.tag;
        if (typeof args[0] === 'string' && args[0].startsWith(clstag)) {
            this.value = new Date(args[0].substr(clstag.length));
        } else {
            this.value = new Date(...args);
        }
    }
    toJSON() {
        return this.constructor.tag + this.value.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    }
}
```

I can add the class to the type registry manually:

```
type_registry[DkDate.tag] = DkDate
```

but is there any way to do this automatically (and only once) from the decorator (or perhaps the base class, or some other way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [current proposal docs](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/blob/master/METAPROGRAMMING.md#examples), you want to add an `extras` property to the class descriptor returned by your decorator, which should contain a "hook" descriptor, and that descriptor should have a `finish` method that will be called with the class itself as an argument once the class is fully defined.

Here's the example code:

```
function defineElement(tagName) {
  return function(classDescriptor) {
    let { kind, elements } = classDescriptor;
    assert(kind == "class");
    return {
      kind,
      elements,

      // This callback is called once the class is otherwise fully defined
      extras: [
        {
          kind: "hook",
          placement: "static",
          finish(klass) {
            window.customElements.define(tagName, klass);
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  };
```

In your case, the `extras` would look like this:

```
extras: [
  {
    kind: "hook",
    placement: "static",
    finish(klass) {
      type_registry[tag] = klass;
    },
  },
],
```

Comment: With `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` 7.3.0 I got `TypeError: A class descriptor can't have a .extras property.`  After much searching I found this (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/commit/b6f592123f33426b2a9c1f3e71335a777d1bd4f9#diff-fa77263addf5d0ae6cc042aac4123adb), and adding `finisher(cls) { type_registry[tag] = cls; }` instead of `extras: ..` seems to work (even if it has been removed from the docs in https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/commit/86b7c09a73e42ca7cebc8324d4a6acdb4ae56c6f#diff-fa77263addf5d0ae6cc042aac4123adb). Such is life on the bleeding edge I guess..

Comment: Looks like it's being worked on right now: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/9360

Comment: Good digging! .